# Incompatible changes in generics in Java 21

Tags: java, generics, jdbi, java-21

Has anyone else also noticed changes in Java's generics in Java 21?

We're using [Jdbi](https://jdbi.org) for database access and when updating to Java 21 things go wrong because a generic type cannot be determined anymore.

While debugging I noticed that a condition

```java
java.lang.reflect.Type type = ...
if (type instanceof Class) {..}
```

where `type` is an interface evaluates to `false` in Java 17 but is `true` in Java 21.

Jdbi depends on the [Geantyref](https://github.com/leangen/geantyref) library for some of its generics. The static method [GenericTypeReflector.getTypeParameter(..)](https://github.com/leangen/geantyref/blob/91ee19aa430752b1872b918d9a2d02efa7126946/src/main/java/io/leangen/geantyref/GenericTypeReflector.java#L389) returns the generic type in Java 17, but returns `null` in Java 21.

Nowhere in the release notes or other announcements I can find anything about that something around generics has changed in Java 21. Nor that there are backwards compatible breaking changes.

I assume some internals might have changed due to record reflection (JEP-440) or the pattern matching for switch (JEP-441), but those features I am already using as 17-preview features without any issue.

Anyone an idea what caused theses changes and why?

#### Update 17-Nov-2023

I think I have figured it out. I trace the problem back to constructor arguments of a record class.
It seems that in Java 21 for a record class somehow the arguments of the default constructor somehow do not have the generic type.
So for a record like

```java
record Person(Optional<String> name, Optional<Integer> age) {}
```

the generic types `String` and `Integer` are lost in the Person's default constructor.
The default constructor generated by Java can be changed by explicitly adding a canonical constructor with all record properties:

```
record Person(Optional<String> name, Optional<Integer> age) {
  @JdbiConstructor
  public Person(Optional<String> aName, Integer anAge) {
    this(aName, anAge);
  }
}
```

By adding the `@JdbiConstructor` annotation (which Jdbi always requires on a Record) Jdbi is instructed which constructor to use.
Because this constructor now explicitly defines the argument types including the generic type, the reflection util is able to determine the type and I got it to work with Java 21.

The last 2 hours I have been trying to create a bare minimum test case to verify that the generic type is lost in the Record's default constructor arguments, but I have not been able to reproduce it in a test. Even though it fails consistently in our application.
I have been comparing type arguments while debugging the application and the test at the same time. The arguments values and types look the same, but the test still succeeds in Java 21.

I'm leaving the test for now since I have to get on with my work and I now do have a working workaround by adding an additional constructor.
I'll try to get back to this later. It must be reproducible in a simple test.

#### Update 20-Nov-2023

Thanks to Holger for creating a small test case proving the issue.

I had 2 things wrong in the 17-Nov update:

- swapping both Optional arguments does *not* create a different constructor since the erased types are equal.
- the default record constructor *can* be overridden by explicitly providing a canonical constructor.

I have updated the 17-Nov update accordingly. Thanks for pointing out these mistakes.

I have submitted a bug report with ID `9076247` which is now under review.

#### Update 22-Nov-2023

The reported bug has been evaluated and assigned Bug ID: JDK-8320575 and is now visible on the url [JDK-8320575](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=JDK-8320575)

Comment: According to the JDBI github page, they run CI tests against Java 21 themselves so that would not really backup that you are immediately projecting problems you are seeing as them being a JDK issue. https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi . You're skipping a few steps here. Like creating a bug report.

Comment: And before you create a bug report, you might want to create a [mre].

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] without any libraries? If not, try creating it with minimal libraries and include the full minimal example in the question.

Comment: Of course I _did_ create a bug report: https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/issues/2527

Comment: I seem to have found the issue. See the update ^^.

Comment: That constructor should not compile.  Method signatures need to be unique after erasure, which means a class can only have one (Optional, Optional) constructor.  In fact, it will not compile for me.

Comment: If  Jdbi always requires the `@JdbiConstructor` annotation on a record, the posted declaration `record Person(Optional<String> name, Optional<Integer> age) {}` does not match the requirement. As said by others, you should post a [mre]

Comment: "*it's not possible to replace the Record's default constructor*" is not 100% correct: 1) a record class does not have a *default constructor*, but a *canonical constructor*; 2) and there are even TWO ways to explicitly declare/replace a *canonical constructor* - Java Language Specification [8.10.4. Record Constructor Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.10.4)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these mistakes. I tried to minimise the example based on the more complex record in our code base and I indeed forgot that swapping 2 Optional types does not make a difference at compile time since the generic types are erased.
And I did not know about the canonical constructor for records, so I learned something new.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem after applying some corrections:

- The problem does not occur when using
  `record Person(Optional<String> name, Optional<Integer> age) {}`
  But since you said, Jdbi always requires the `@JdbiConstructor` annotation on a record, I assume that you provided an annotated compact constructor. *Then*, the problem occurs.
- Your fix does not work at all. When swapping the two parameters, both of type `Optional`, you get a constructor with the same erasure as the canonical constructor. This is not accepted by a correct compiler and even if a compiler accepted it, it would break at runtime.
- It’s not correct that the canonical constructor can’t be fixed. You can create an explicit canonical constructor instead of the compact one.

Using the following test program:

```java
import java.util.Optional;

public class Reproducer {
    interface NoConstructorDeclarations {
        record Person(Optional<String> name, Optional<Integer> age) {}
    }

    interface AnnotatedCompactConstructor {
        record Person(Optional<String> name, Optional<Integer> age) {
            @Deprecated public Person {}
        }
    }

    interface AnotatedExplicitCanonicalConstructor  {
        record Person(Optional<String> name, Optional<Integer> age) {
            @Deprecated
            public Person(Optional<String> name, Optional<Integer> age) {
                this.name = name;
                this.age = age;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for(var approach: Reproducer.class.getDeclaredClasses()) {
            Class<?> recordClass = approach.getClasses()[0];
            System.out.println(approach.getSimpleName());
  
            var constructor = recordClass.getConstructors()[0];
            System.out.println(constructor.isAnnotationPresent(Deprecated.class));
            for(var p: constructor.getParameters()) {
                System.out.println(p);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

and `javac` from JDK 21, I get:

```
AnotatedExplicitCanonicalConstructor
true
java.util.Optional<java.lang.String> name
java.util.Optional<java.lang.Integer> age

AnnotatedCompactConstructor
true
 java.util.Optional name
 java.util.Optional age

NoConstructorDeclarations
false
java.util.Optional<java.lang.String> name
java.util.Optional<java.lang.Integer> age
```

which acknowledges the problem and demonstrates a workaround. This problem does not occur with `javac` of previous JDKs nor Eclipse’s compiler.

I used `@Deprecated` instead of `@JdbiConstructor`, to make the example independent from 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Thanks @Holger for finding a reproducer. Someone should probably submit this as a bug to the JDK folks - they usually take incorrect compilation fairly seriously. Since it's your code, you get first dibs, otherwise someone else should :)

Comment: PS, we still use your memoizing supplier implementation you shared back in 2016, so thanks for that!

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out with a simple test case.